# Replacement for System.Data.dll for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, dll, windows-phone-8.1, system.data

I am having trouble while adding `System.Data.dll` in Windows Phone 8.1 Application. Following compile time error show after adding `System.Data.dll` in project reference and adding following class:

```
public class EntityResponse
{
    public DataSet[] EntityDataSet { get; set; }
}
```

> *The base class or interface 'System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent' in assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type 'System.Data.DataSet' could not be resolved   c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll*

Please let me know what is problem and how we can solve this problem with other replacement class or dll.

Comment: Well you just can't use System.Data in Windows Phone 8 applications because it's not supported on WinRT. There are other options (a middle tier if you're running on desktop or Local Database if you're running on RT) but you need to explain what you need it for. If you need Entities...well you can't. You have a basic ORM support in Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq.Mapping (and _friends_) but nothing like EF.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I like to use `DataSet`, `DataTable`.. ADO.net component in project.

Comment: Sorry you can't. All that stuff isn't supported, see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx (and sub-topics). Well _"you can't"_ actually means you can't use those objects but you can do more or less same things in another way.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I like parse Json object response which might having DataSet property, how can I parse same object in alternate way in windows phone 8.1?

Comment: Do you have a DataSet object **serialized** in JSON?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes, DataSet object serialized in JSON.

Comment: Well you still can deserialize it (it depends what you used to do it) but you won't have its methods nor controls to use it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62581/discussion-between-ankush-madankar-and-adriano-repetti).